# querySelector before the element creation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to organize my code with first, declaration of my elements as variables with querySelector, then, my main, then, declaration of my functions.
But some of my elements are created later with a fetch for exemple, as a result, the variables set at first is null, but if I call the querySelector instead, it works.
What would be the right way to do it please ?

Here's my code so far :

```
// Elements
var header = document.querySelector("header");
var userBlockLogged = document.querySelector("header .user.logged");

// Main
window.onload=function(){
    main();
}
function main(){
    load(header,"./pages/header.html",step_headerLoaded);
}

// Functions
function load(node,page,callback){
    fetch(page)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        node.innerHTML = body;
        callback();
    });
}
function step_headerLoaded(){
    console.log(document.querySelector("header .user.not-logged"));
    console.log(userBlockNotLogged);
    userBlockLogged.classList.remove("display-none");// returns an error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variables first, then assign them in `onload`.

```
// Elements
var header;
var userBlockLogged;

// Main
window.onload = main;

function main(){
    header = document.querySelector("header");
    userBlockLogged = header.querySelector(".user.logged");
    load(header,"./pages/header.html",step_headerLoaded);
}

// Functions
function load(node,page,callback){
    fetch(page)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        node.innerHTML = body;
        callback();
    });
}
function step_headerLoaded(){
    console.log(document.querySelector("header .user.not-logged"));
    console.log(userBlockNotLogged);
    userBlockLogged.classList.remove("display-none");// returns an error
}
```

Notice also that I removed the anonymous function around the call to `main()`.

```
window.onload = main;
```

And I changed the second `querySelector` to fetch it from the `header`, so that the context is limited, and its selector is simplified.

```
userBlockLogged = header.querySelector(".user.logged");
```

Finally, note that `window.onload` is delayed until all external page assets are loaded. You may want to use an event that happens once the elements are available.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could do the declaration and assignment at the same place to be easier, but seems not then.
I'll also implement your others advice, thanks ^^